# How do I add a `relation` to my PostgresQL database using Typeorm?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

For example

```js
@Entity()
class Post {

  @Column()
  post_hash: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  categorys:  Array<Category> = []; 
}
```

```js
@Entity()
class Category {

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @Column()
  post_hash: number;

}
```

I want to query all the `category` content of the corresponding `post` through Typeorm.

I tried this method and failed.

```js
this.createQueryBuilder('Post').leftJoinAndMapOne(
            'Post.categorys',
             Category,
            'category',
            'category.post_hash = post.post_hash'
      )
```

This is my error message.
  `QueryFailedError: relation "post" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

## Entities

First of all, you must [identify each row with a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466553/use-of-an-id-in-databases) using [`@PrimaryColumn()`](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/primarycolumn) or [`@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/primarygeneratedcolumn) decorators.

Each `Post` entity can have multiple *categories* and each `Category` entity is related to multiple *posts*.
This is called a [**many-to-many**](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations) relation and must be correctly mapped using the [`@ManyToMany()`](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/manytomany) decorator.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113885/difference-between-one-to-many-many-to-one-and-many-to-many) for more information.

```js
@Entity()
class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  post_hash: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, category => category.posts)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @Column()
  post_hash: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Post, post => post.categories)
  posts: Post[];
}
```

## Query

Obtain all `Post`(s) with the related *categories*.

Using [`find`](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options):

```js
const posts: Post[] = await getRepository(Post)
                             .find({ relations: ['categories'] });
```

Using [`QueryBuilder`](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/joining-relations):

```js
const posts: Post[] = await getRepository(Post)
                             .createQueryBuilder('post')
                             .leftJoinAndSelect('post.categories', 'category')
                             .getMany();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still want to ask about the way to write one-to-many relationships (post->Categories), post and category are just a few examples I've provided

Comment: If you want multiple posts to have multiple categories and vice versa multiple categories to be mapped to multiple posts you must use N-to-N relation. If you want an array where each element is a foreign key this is not possible -> see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key).